# RoR - Issue with routes using Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, routes

I'm working in an API with rails using Devise for user authentication.

As I want to use custom routes I'd changed muy routes.rb like this:

```
devise_scope :users do
    post "/sessions", :to => "sessions#create"
    delete "/sessions", :to => "sessions#destroy"

    post "/user", :to => "users#create"
end
```

I'm having the following error when I wan to logout the user (DELETE /sessions)

```
def self.logout token
    response = RestClient.delete  "http://localhost:3000/sessions/", {'ACCEPT' => "application/json", 'user_token' => token }
    puts response.to_s
end
```

> Started DELETE "/sessions/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-03 14:26:37 -0300
>   Processing by SessionsController#destroy as JSON [Devise] Could not
>   find devise mapping for path "/sessions". This may happen for two
>   reasons:
>
> 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. 2) You are
>   testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 16ms

This is my SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:destroy]
  respond_to :json

  def destroy
    user_token = params[:user_token].presence
    user       = user_token && User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token)

    #if user.nil?
    #  render :json=> {:success=>false}
    #end

    resource.authentication_token = nil
    resource.save
    render :json=> {:success=>true}
  end

end
```

The other routes are working fine (login => POST /sessions, signup => POST /users).

Someone has idea why it is throwing 404?

Thanks